# Date Command in Linux Desktop File Bash Command

Tags: linux

This is a rather specific question about the date command on linux when it is part of a bash command in a desktop file.

**Environment:** ubuntu 16.04

I have a desktop file that executes a bash command that runs a scripts and redirects its output to a dated log file. The bash command itself works fine if run directly from the terminal:

```
bash -c "/path/to/script &> /var/log/$(date +%Y%m%d).out"
```

The above command creates a file such as `/var/log/20190413.out`. However, if I use this command as part of a desktop file, the script is run but the output file is not created. This is a sample desktop file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=bash -c "/path/to/script &> /var/log/$(date +%Y%m%d).out"
```

This seems to be specific to the `date` command. If I replace it in my desktop file with `$(hostname)`, for instance, it logs to `/var/log/<my hostname>.out`.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there something strange happening behind the scenes? **Note:** I'm not looking for a work-around so much as I want to understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the percent sign in the argument to the date command. It is a special character in desktop files even though it is in a double quoted argument. To escape it, use "%%" instead. This is well documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables).